# Do you need to do port forward when a PC is plugged directly in to a very basic cable modem?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, modem

If I plug my very basic cable modem directly in to a desktop computer, would it be necessary to configure port settings, or should it work if my firewall is off?

I'm looking to connect to a specific port on a PC through a modem.

My modem doesn't have any WiFi, and the settings don't display a port forwarding menu. Do modems exist that do not allow port forwarding at all?

Comment: You only need to worry about port forwarding if NAT is in the picture. If you still have a public IP address, then your PC is more or less open to the internet. If however the modem does NAT (you have an internal IP and not a public IP on your PC) then port forwarding is the way that the modem would know which external port maps to which internal port and internal address. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding for more detail. Keep in mind that opening a port and forwarding a port are two different things. If you have a firewall in the modem, you may need to tell it to open a port.

Answer (score 2):

> If I plug my very basic cable modem directly in to a desktop computer, would it be necessary to configure port settings, or should it work if my firewall is off?
>
> I'm looking to connect to a specific port on a PC through a modem.

Based on your edit, if you connect the modem directly to your PC then your PC’s firewall will manage port forwarding. A modem connected directly to a PC is just a “dumb” media converter and not much else. Heck, if you dropped your firewall completely you can then just access any open port on your PC… But obviously that is not ideal.